# Different page loaded via https and http

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I have a shared hosting (economy plan) with Godaddy. I tied my domain name to the hosting. I also use cloudflare and its SSL settings. I changed the namservers in Godaddy as instructed by cloudflare.

When I try to reach my site via http everything is ok. But when I try to reach it via https I get the default Godaddy greeting page:

> Future home of something quite cool.

I use the "FULL" SSL settings in Cloudflare.

Any idea why I cannot access my site via https?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more trial and error I figured it out.

I had to set SSL to flexible and "Always use HTTPS" on at cloudlare.

I'm using WordPress so I also had to install "CloudFlare Flexible SSL" plugin, because my styles were broken.